# Problem with Mesa 3d Inteldriver

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, mesa

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with the following graphic card

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor 
Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5024]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I have a graphic problem with a game which is discussed [here](http://us.battle.net/en/forum/topic/14728822920?page=1).

I found [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/5642959-distorted-graphics-or-black-window-when-running-battle-net-app-on-intel-hardware-via-wine) that the problem is caused by the Intel driver (or Mesa 3D?) and that it was fixed. But where can I find and install the fixed Intel driver?

I downloaded Mesalib 10.4.3 extracted it, and typed in a shell

```
./configure
make
```

both execution succeeded without a error. However, the graphic error remained. Have I missed anything important?

Answer (score 0):

For one, you must do "make install" to install the compiled drivers. You may also need to set the configure options.

Comment: Thank you for pitching in! your answer would be much improved if you would expand it with pertinent examples such that the OP can follow. I thank you and the community thanks you! :-)